# It's possible using Spring Web Mvc without annotations?

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm doing a training in computer consulting company.
The project manager gave me an exercise to do with spring web mvc where do I get the data sent from a form and I need to display them on another page. I did it, all right, and I used the annotation of spring mvc.

Now the project manager told me to do the reengineering exercise,
doing it without using the annotation.

I searched on 10 sites including:
tutorialspoint, html.it, mykong, and documentation of spring mvc web and I saw that spring web mvc only works with the annotation, the annotation that I used are nell'esrcizio @ RequestMapping, @ Controller, @ ModelAttribute.

Thank you

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can use xml configuration refer this link, if it helps you then up vote please

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/beans-spring/spring-3-hello-world-example/

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-example/

Comment: It's not a stackoverflow answer. If you want help write codes here. Don't share link.

Comment: It's not about owning. This is the rule. When you post an answer like that you get negative points. It's a advice for you. Don't be arrogant.

Comment: Neither of those links were any help - both described Spring with annotations which is exactly what the OP didn't want. Sorry, -1